# How to solve Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.DataTable' ERROR

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview, devexpress

i have Devxpress GridControl on the form,
and i want to send data on this grid to excel.
and i dont want to do this with ExportToExcel method
i have googled and found this code
but this code is for DataGrid control of .Net
and it gives an error when it tries to convert 
 DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView to System.Data.DataView
here is the code

```
public string LastCoulmLetter(int coulmnCount)
{
        string finalColLetter = string.Empty;
        string colCharset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int colCharsetLen = colCharset.Length;

        if (coulmnCount > colCharsetLen)
        {
            finalColLetter = colCharset.Substring(
                (coulmnCount - 1) / colCharsetLen - 1, 1);
        }

        finalColLetter += colCharset.Substring(
                (coulmnCount - 1) % colCharsetLen, 1);

        return finalColLetter;
}


public void FromGridToExcel()
{
        if (gridView1.RowCount <= 0)
            return;
        Excel.Application xls = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb;
        Excel.Worksheet sheet;

        object SalakObje = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        wb = xls.Workbooks.Add(SalakObje);
        sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;
        sheet.Name = "Result";
        xls.Visible = true;

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)gridView1.DataSource; // Error comes in here

        // Copy the DataTable to an object array
        object[,] rawData = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1, dt.Columns.Count];

        // Copy the column names to the first row of the object array
        for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            rawData[0, col] = dt.Columns[col].ColumnName;
        }

        // Copy the values to the object array
        for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                rawData[row + 1, col] = dt.Rows[row].ItemArray[col];
            }
        }

        // Fast data export to Excel
        string excelRange = string.Format("A1:{0}{1}",LastCoulmLetter(dt.Columns.Count), dt.Rows.Count + 1);

        sheet.get_Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData;

        sheet.get_Range(excelRange).Columns.AutoFit();
}
```

So what is the problem and how to fix it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your `DataSource` is a `DataView`, not a `DataTable`.

Some options:

Cast it to a `DataView` if you want to use the same filters:

```
DataView dv = (DataView)gridView1.DataSource;
```

Use the `.Table` property to get the source table if you want the raw data:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataView)gridView1.DataSource).Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataView)gridView1.DataSource).Table;
```